# adding a codable model to realm swift

Tags: swift, realm, codable

I am trying to add a **Codable** model to a realm DB. The model works and values are passed from an **API** call how ever, I want to create a **Array** in my **Realm** DB so when I hit a save button, the Model is added to DB.

how ever I get this error for my create

> Cannot convert value of type 'Data?' to expected argument type
>   'Object'

```
func create<T: Object>(_ objects: [T]) where T: Codable {
        do {
            let placesData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(objects)
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(placesData)
            }
        } catch {
        }
    }
```

saving in UserDefaults is like this

```
private func putModelArray<T>(_ value: [T]?, forKey key: String) where T: Codable {
        guard let value = value else {
            storage.removeObject(forKey: key)
            return
        }
        let placesData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(value)
        storage.setValue(placesData, forKey: key)
    }
```

Comment: extract all values from Data into your class object, and then put your class object into realm.

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry can you show code sample please

Comment: What is the goal to encode a Realm Object to JSON and save that in the database?

Comment: can you print the placesData variable and add into your question.

Comment: If you already have an array of objects, why would you want to JSON encode it before saving to realm? Simply do `realm.add(objects)`.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
realm.add(placesData)
```

takes an `object` argument while you send `Data` to it

> if you get data from json and for it you use Decodable that doesn't mean you have to use Encodable

Comment: so how do I save this in Realm? because I cannot save the Codable model as it is into the DB

Comment: Using Realm, I have to conform to Encodable

Comment: try `realm.add(objects) `compile ?

Comment: `Cannot convert value of type 'UInt8?' to expected argument type 'Object'`